# IOS trying to add an image from uiimagepicker to a uicollectionview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to load an image via imagepicker and insert it into an array so that I can push it to an new UIcollectionview cell as below after the imagepicker has been called:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    testPicture = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];   

    NSLog(@"%@", testPicture);
```

below is where I'm trying to load the image into a new array:

```
NSArray *newData =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: testPicture , nil];
 [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        int resultsSize = [self.data count]; //data is the previous array of data
        [self.data addObjectsFromArray:newData];
        NSMutableArray *arrayWithIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = resultsSize; i < resultsSize + newData.count; i++)
        {
            [arrayWithIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        }
        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayWithIndexPaths];

     }
}
```

It works if I call an image from a previously loaded array:

```
NSArray *newData =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"my_image.jpeg" , nil];
```

Otherwise I get a length error, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

the value of UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage
Specifies the original, uncropped image selected by the user.

The value for this key is a UIImage object.

It is not a image path, may be your collectionView bind the wrong data type.